# Correct way to ask "no chance you can do it?"

Tags: questions, negation, existentials

Which one sounds more natural to a native speaker?

### #1

> So, no chance to do it?
>
> *I think there maybe is*

### #2

> So no way you can do it?
>
> *I probably can*

Or is there a better phrase that a native speaker would use?

There has to be negation in the question. It can't be like "*Can you do this?*".

Comment: Could you please add some more context? Are you asking someone to do something that they say can’t be done? Are you and someone else contemplating doing something together?

Comment: _So, no chance of doing it? I think maybe there is._

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this as an improvement to the first sentence?
"So, no chance **of you doing** it? - I think there maybe is"

I do think the latter option is more natural for a speaker though.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with "Any chance you can do this?"

Comment: You're generally asked to provide an explanation with your answer in order to provide high quality answers. - [From Review](http://ell.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/44165)

Comment: And note that OP asks specifically that there be a negation.